# Using jquery to load items on quiz. Why am I losing button to select next item when loaded?

Tags: php, jquery

I am dynamically loading question content into a div using jquery . This is my first attempt and it does load when I click the "Get Question"-button. However, the "Get Question"-button disappears when the question loads. I want the button to stay and eventually use it as a next  question button.

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(
$("#GetQuest").click(function(){
    $.post("CCRN/question.php", {num : parseInt($("input#q_num").val()) + 1}, function (data) {
        $("div#question").html(data);
        $("input#q_num").val() =  parseInt($("input#q_num").val()) + 1;
    });
});
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="GetQuest" value="Get Question" />
<input type="hidden" id="q_num" value=1 />
<p>Question: <div id="question"> </div></p>
<p>Answer: <div id="answer"> </div></p>
```

Here is the question creating code (though the question loads and display fine)

```
<table width="100%"><?php
$i = $q_num;
if ($row["image"] <> NULL) { ?>
 <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <img src="<?php $pic = $row["image"]; echo $base_path . $pic; ?>" />
    </td>
 </tr><br />
<tr>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php
 } ?>
<tr id="Qu<?php echo $i; ?>" class="Qu<?php echo $i; ?>">
<td width="7%"><?php echo $i.") " ?></td>
<td width="93%" ><?php echo $row["question"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
for ($j=1;$j<=6;$j++) { 
$bracket= "answer_" . $j;
if ($row[$bracket] !== NULL) {?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="row<?php echo $j % 2; ?>" width="7%">
            <input type="radio" <?php echo ($_POST["Q".$i] == $j) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ; ?> name="Q<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $j; ?>" /><?php echo chr(64 + $j); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="row<?php echo $j % 2; ?>" width="93%">
            <?php echo $row["answer_".$j]; ?>
        </td>
    </tr> <?php
}
} ?>
</table><hr size="2" width="95%">
```

I do not understand why the button disappears when I load the question content. I am SURE it is something embarassing simple, which is why I am coming to a safe haven to minimize the ridicule! :)

Live test site http://www.GrowingSpeakers.com/index2.php to see the disappearing button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using div with id "question" before.

```
<div class="TabbedPanelsContent" id="question">
```

and

```
<p>Question: <div id="question"> </div></p>
```

It does not matter even though the id's come from different files as long as they are displayed in the same DOM tree - they will be treated as one and the same.

Comment: thank you. the second id_"question" is not here in the question, but is in the index2.php file went unnoticed by my old and tired eyes. Thanks! I would up vote, but I am too low in reputation. Will do so when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 div's with the ID question and the javascript is going to replace the content of the first one found when you run:

```
 $("div#question").html(data);
```

if you change the id for the first one it should work fine.

Comment: I only have one div with id question. the other question is question.php the file the creates the question.

Comment: On the live example that you gave, you had 2 that had an id of question before you changed it to quest_div.

Comment: Can I ask another question regarding this code? why is the value of the hidden inpout field not increasing when I click on the Get question button? it is supposed to increment it so the next ajax jquery request gets the next numbered question.

Comment: never mind! was treating val() as a variable and not a method.